# Best E-Collar for cat post Perineal Urethrostomy (PU) surgery?

Tags: cats, surgery

I have a cat who had to have a PU surgery and now has a traditional cheap plastic E-Collar held on with a gauze band.

He's scratching his neck at the gauze and there's a good chance he will get the cone loose if he continues.

Opting for improving the cone a bit there seems to be quite a variety of cone solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try an [ez-soft e-collar](http://www.vetrimark.com/core/media/media.nl?id=46434&c=ACCT123382&h=dfed198e408a88a327d4), we usually send home our cat patients with them. They tolerate them much better as it's lighter and less clumsy, if you see it doesn't work for your kitty you could always return it.

there is also the [cloud collar](https://1mpr64kkw06av2tn1d975o3k-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Cloud_collar-700x700.jpg) as well.

Comment: A cloud collar would not block access to the area affected by a PU (hind quarters) unfortunately. The ez-soft e-collar looks pretty good but the description says it is made of pliable fabric which would get scrunched and not effectively block access. Also it blocks peripheral visibility (not transparent).

Comment: Cats can't scrunch them, this is true for our dogs which is why we never sell them for the big guys.

Comment: If it's possible at all, my guy will do it. He's an animal but I may try it nonetheless. Currently I am trying this one: http://www.petsmart.com/dog/supplies-and-training/collars-harnesses-and-leashes/collars/21st-centurys-protective-e-collar-37007.html?cgid=100081 which is at least an improvement in that the edge is rounded and stitched with some kind of pleather material which is much less rough when he rubs/smacks it all around down there.